# Get the Controller Name and Method Name in ASP.NET-Core 2.2 Controller

Tags: c#, controller, httpcontext, asp.net-core-2.2

I know that in asp.net-core 2.2, I can get the action name as follows:

```
ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
```

but I am looking for a way to get the controller name of the current request/page in asp.net-core 2.2

I will appreciate any guide.

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have access to controller name  in the

```
ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName
```

property, given that the action descriptor is of [`ControllerActionDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-2.2) type

Reference [ControllerActionDescriptor.ControllerName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor.controllername?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Controllers_ControllerActionDescriptor_ControllerName)

Answer (score 7):

I know It's late but maybe someone can benefit from it

```
ControllerName: ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName 
ActionName: ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
```

Answer (score 0):

There are situations where your ControllerContext will be null and you end up with nothing. I recommend using reflection.

```
this.GetType().Name
```

Comment: this doesn't help if your contoller type name is, e.g.: `ValuesController` but your controller name is actually `Values`

Comment: ASP.NET MVC uses that naming convention for all controllers.  Not sure what are you trying to say @Zac.

Comment: I'm saying that for something like `Url.Action(...)` where one of the parameters is a Controller name, if you pass it `ValuesController` like you'd get from your solution, it doesn't work, but if you pass it `Values` instead it *does* work. Your way would get `ValuesController`, but the accepted `ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName` gives the correct `Values` for that situation

Comment: Again, there are situations where your ControllerContext will be null and you end up with nothing, therefore you will pass a null value to the Url.Action()?..Using reflection you will always get the name of the controller, no matter what is the state of the context, and you can easily remove the "Controller" part safely, since, like I also mentioned this is part of a naming convention. so, steps, get the name using reflection, remove the ending "Controller" from the string..and you should be ok.